# Can't open app thumbnails on Win7 toolbar

Tags: windows-7

This has just recently started to occur.  If I open more than one instance of a program (Word, Excel, Firefox etc.) and then minimize them, when I mouse over the app in the toolbar, I see both instances, but when I try to click on either, both thumbnails disappear and I am no longer able to access either.  Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution?  Thanks

Comment: This could be similar to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/377279/windows-7-cant-reopen-minimised-window-on-taskbar-preview-ok